# Didn't get the ID from database based on row table

Tags: php

Why I can't get the ID from a row in table when I click `Pending`

Here is the code:

```
<!-- ############################################################################################################################################################################################################ -->
<!-- TABLE BUSINESS -->
<div class="row" id="TblBiz" style="display: none;">
            <div class="col" style="height: 71px;">
                <h1 style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-weight: 300;">Business</h1>
            </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
                <div class="panel" id="main">
                    <div class="container-fluid container-bg">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table id="myTable4" class="table table-hover table-dark" style="font-size:11px; margin-top:6px;">
                                <thead style="font-size: 18px;">
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Business ID</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Owner</th>
                                    <th>View</th>
                                    <th>Approval</th>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php
                                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mechanic_business";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
                                    
                                        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                                    
                                        $i = 1;
                                    
                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                            $biz_ID = $row['businessID'];
                                            $mech_ID = $row['mechID'];
                                            $mech_name = $row['mech_name'];
                                            $bizName = $row['business_name'];
                                            $bizApprove = $row['business_approval_status'];
                                            $bizStatus = $row['business_status'];
                                            // $dateJoin = $row['DATE_REGISTERED'];
                                            // $dateFormated = date("d M Y", strtotime($dateJoin));

                                            // Color class in PHP color(Pending, Approved, Banned)
                                            $color = ($bizApprove === 'Pending') ? '#f0ad4e' : (($bizApprove === 'Approved') ? '#28a745' : '#dc3545');

                                                echo "<tr style='font-size:18px;'>";
                                                echo "<td class='align-middle'>" . $i; $i++ . "</td>";
                                                echo "<td class='align-middle'>" . $biz_ID . "</td>";
                                                echo "<td class='align-middle'>". $bizName ."</td>";
                                                echo "<td class='align-middle'>". $mech_name ."</td>";
                                                echo "<td class='align-middle'><input type='button' name='view' value='view' id='". $biz_ID ."' class='btn btn-info btn-xs view_biz'></td>";
                                                echo "<td class='align-middle'><a role='button' class='approval-bton' id='". $biz_ID ."' style='color:". $color ."';>". $bizApprove ."</a></td>"; 
                                                echo "</tr>";
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                            echo "<td colspan='7' class='table-active align-middle'>No Record in Database</td>";
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
<!-- ############################################################################################################################################################################################################ -->

<!-- ############################################################################################################################################ -->
<!-- UPDATE APPROVE STATUS MODAL -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="approveModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> Update Business Approval Status </h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>

                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <input type="text" name="businessID" id="" value="<?php echo $biz_ID; ?>">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div>
                                <small id="photoHelp" class="form-text text-muted"><span style="color: #FF0000;">*</span><em>320px x 320px is ideal dimension, Format: jpg, png, jpeg, and PDF only</em></small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" name="updateApprove" class="btn btn-primary">Save Change</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- ############################################################################################################################################ -->
```

When I clicked a `Pending` from each row it suppose to get their `ID` based on the database but when I clicked from each row they display the same `ID` as shown picture in the link below.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IcfDUs3Q8Wl5vVO3KF793M5noTukLrCL/view?usp=sharing

They both show `ORVA01BIZ-00000002` but in database first row is `ORVA01BIZ-00000001` and `ORVA01BIZ-00000002` is the second row and goes on.

Comment: As a note, `echo "<td class='align-middle'>" . $i; $i++ . "</td>";` isn't doing what you think it is. `echo "<td class='align-middle'>" . $i`;` is one statement, `$i++ . "</td>";` is another, and isn't echoed.

Comment: Your modal is not part of the loop, so only shows the last `$biz_ID` created. You should probably use javascript to pass the information along to the modal instead.

Comment: as @anyber suggested, `value="<?php echo $biz_ID; ?>"` it's a totally wrong approach. Since the moment the page get returned, there's no further interaction with the server side. Since you already have the needed information on each row, you need to populate that information with a client side logic in javascript that will retrieve the ID from the clicked row and display that info there in place of the php tag I highlighted before

Comment: do u have any idea to do that? sorry my javascript skill is very bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is very simple logic.

1. first, your model is not in loop so you can't pass $biz_ID in the model if you want to get each id from the database.

When the loop ends then it will only print the last row biz_id in the model.

The solution is :-

Changes you have to do in your code

You have to do one thing if you want to get each id

This is your second td :-

1. `echo "<td class='align-middle bizzid'>" . $biz_ID . "</td>";`

In your model you have to paste this : -

1. `<input type="text" name="businessID" id="businessID" value="">`-

This jquery code can help you to get desired result.

```
 var bizid = $(this).closest('tr').find('.bizzid').text();
 $('#businessID').val(bizid);
 $('#approveModal').modal('show');
 });'
```

Comment: `echo "<td class='align-middle bizzid'>" . $biz_ID . "</td>";` this one do I have to put the `bizzid` inside the class?

Comment: hey @Gurpreet Kait can i ask why that works on the first 10 when comes to eleventh row it doesn't work anymore when I click pending.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it

I did what you asked @Gurpreet Kait it really workss.

I put the jquery code inside the initialize modal bootstrap

```
// Show Modal 1
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.approval-bton').on('click', function() {
      var bizid = $(this).closest('tr').find('.bizzid').text();
      $('#businessID').val(bizid);
      $('#approveModal').modal('show');

  });
```

Thank you very much @Gurpreet Kait for your help.
});

Comment: Can anyone vote my answer for +15 in order for me to vote to anyone. Currently I don't have reputation in stackoverflow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, If you would like to gain more reputation I would suggest making some contributions with unique questions and/or helpful answers. As for this question, if @Gurpreet Kait's already solved your question, there is no need to make a separate answer confirming this; just upvote and click the check mark to accept it as the answer to said question.